# AppleScript not working after 10.15.4 update

Tags: applescript

I have simple scripts to turn down the brightness of my MacBook via an AppleScript.  This worked fine in Catalina 10.15.3, but has stopped working after I upgraded to 10.15.4.

The script is as follows:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    set value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 to 0.0
end tell
```

..error is as follows:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window \"Built-in Retina Display\" of process \"System Preferences\". Invalid index." number -1719 from slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window "Built-in Retina Display" of process "System Preferences"
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolution information in case anybody else has the same issue...

(Courtesy of cheeseb on the Apple Developer forums):

GUI Scripting is inherently sensitive to changes in application interfaces from version to version. In your case, the Built-in Retina Display window in System Preferences lost the "group 1" UI Element in macOS Catalina 10.15.4. So you should be able to fix the problem by changing the 'set value' line of your script to 'value indicator 1 of slider 1 of tab group 1'. I have not tested this, but my UI Browser application shows this to be the new element path.